# using Linq Except method on SPFieldUserValueCollection

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2013

I'm new to SharePoint and faced the problem below:

I have an `EventReceiver` with an `ItemUpdating` method where I can get values from a multivalue user field with `BeforeProperties` and `AfterProperties`.

I would like to get the differences and store them in variables `onlyBefore` and `onlyAfter` SPFieldUserValueCollections.

onlyBefore should be equal to values that are only in the `beforeChangeValues`.
`onlyAfter` should be equal to values that are only in the `afterChangeValues`.

Excerpt of my code:

```
SPWeb web = properties.OpenWeb();
SPFieldUserValueCollection beforeChangeValues = properties.ListItem["HumanResources"] as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
SPFieldUserValueCollection afterChangeValues = new SPFieldUserValueCollection(web, properties.AfterProperties["HumanResources"].ToString());
```

I would like to get the differences of two SPFieldUserValueCollections but the `onlyAfter` and `onlyBefore` are always null

```
IEnumerable<SPFieldUserValue> onlyBefore = beforeChangeValues.Except(afterChangeValues) as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
IEnumerable<SPFieldUserValue> onlyAfter = afterChangeValues.Except(beforeChangeValues) as SPFieldUserValueCollection;
```

Unfortunately `onlyBefore` and `onlyAfter` are always null.
Can you help me with how should I use the `Except` method to get the difference from two SPFieldUserValueCollections?

Or is it a completely wrong solution and I should convert and work with arrays instead of collections?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I indented your code sample by 4 spaces so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in the specific error-message you're encountering in case that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure that you are getting them null because you are using `as SPFieldUserValueCollection` which is an invalid cast, try to do a `.ToList()` instead